# Least Square Cross Validation for Density Estimation with Histograms

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cross-validation, kernel-smoothing, histogram, density-estimation

In a 1981 paper by Rudemo an easy to compute expression for the integrated squared error of a histogram relative to the true distribution is derived (Eq. 2.8 of the [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4615859.pdf) and the last equation in this post).

The idea is to choose the bin sizes of a histogram in order minimize the least square error between the true density $p(x)$ and the histogram density $\hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}}(x)$ computed with bin sizes $\{\Delta_k\}$ and $k \in [1, K]$ (in the simplest case the bins are all equal and $\Delta_k = \Delta$). So we have

$$\mathcal{L}(\{\Delta_k\}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}}(x) - p(x)\right]^2 \mathrm{d}x$$

This is the *integrated square error* and it can be expanded in 3 terms

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}}(x)\right]^2 \mathrm{d}x - 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}}(x) p(x)\right] \mathrm{d}x + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ p(x)\right]^2 \mathrm{d}x $$

We can ignore the last term since it is independent of $\{\Delta_k\}$. The first term can be computed exactly because we know $\hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}}(x)$. The second term can be thought of as the average "height" of the histogram under the true distribution. Rudemo proposes to approximate this expectation through a leave-one-out estimator, so that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}}(x) p(x)\right]\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}, -i}(x_i)$$

where N is the number of observations and $\hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}, -i}(x)$ represents the estimated density (histogram "height") at point $x_i$ computed by excluding point $x_i$ from the density estimation. The cost function to minimize can then be written as

$$\begin{aligned} 
\mathcal{L}(\{\Delta_k\}) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}}(x)\right]^2 - \frac{2}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \hat{p}_{\{\Delta_k\}, -i}(x_i) \\
&= \frac{2}{N(N-1)} \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{n_k}{\Delta_k} - \frac{N+1}{N^2(N-1)}\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{n^2_k}{\Delta_k}
\end{aligned}$$

where $n_k$ is the number of observations in bin $\Delta_k$. Is anyone aware of how to derive this last result? I have found this theorem in a number of places but none of them provides a proof. If it's of any use, the equivalent result for generic kernels can be found in a paper by Scott, see Eq. 3.8 of this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2289391?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), and its derivation is available in a number of other sources e.g. Sivlerman's book on density estimation (page 49).

Comment: Does it hold that: $\hat{p}_{\Delta_k}(x) = \frac{1}{\Delta_k}\sum_{k=1}^K n_k \mathbb{1}_{k\Delta_k}(x)$?

Comment: I think you are missing a factor of 1/N to get a valid density that integrates to 1.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. Did you try to use this representation of the estimator to calculate the equality?

Comment: You can find a proof on chapter 3 of Linhart and Zucchini's 'Model Selection'.